# Filter on Two columns with Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that I want to filter.I am filtering on a tag with the following formula

`FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I, "BREAD"))`

However I am only interested in matches between for certain dates (let's say January -March 2023). How do I apply this second filter to the formula. Is it some sort of chain of formulas ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Add more two condition to your formula `=FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I, "BREAD"),DateColumn>=StartDate,DateColumn<=EndDate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to provide a proper response to the question. I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the solution was provided in the comments section.

I used the following formula:

```
=FILTER(A1:A,REGEXMATCH(A1:A, "BREAD"),B1:B>=DATE(2023,1,1),B1:B<=DATE(2023,3,31))
```

My sample data is the following:
[image: sampleData]

Comment: hi @Lorena Gomez, thanks for the answer. I have tried to run the formula before I select it as correct.
```
=FILTER(I2:P,REGEXMATCH(I2:I; "BREAD),A2:A>=DATE(2023,1,1),A2:A<=DATE(2023,3,31))
```

However I get a formula parse error.

The date format is day.month.year and the csv was downloaded from a German website. I changed the local to  Germany but to no avail. Do these details explain the parse error ?

Comment: I changed the date format to day/month/year and it worked. Thanks